# Rails 4 + Capistrano 3 - Deploy to Production Server from Local Repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano3

I'm using Windows 10 and Cygwin, and I am setting up Capistrano 3 for deployment to my production environment. I believe I have everything set up correctly, but I can't figure out how to push my local repo to my production server. I don't have my repo on GitHub or another such site and would like to keep it local. I receive the following error message when I run `cap production deploy`.

> SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as
>   myappuser@myappname.website.com: git exit status: 128 git stdout:
>   Nothing written git stderr: fatal: No remote configured to list refs
>   from.
>
> SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128 git stdout: Nothing
>   written git stderr: fatal: No remote configured to list refs from.
>
> Tasks: TOP => git:check (See full trace by running task with --trace)
>   The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as
>   myappuser@myappname.website.com: git exit status : 128 git stdout:
>   Nothing written git stderr: fatal: No remote configured to list refs
>   from.

Here's my `config\deploy.rb` file:

```
# config valid only for current version of Capistrano
lock '3.4.0'

set :application, 'myappname
set :deploy_user, 'myappuser'
set :repo_url, "file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/repo/myappname.git"

# setup rvm.
set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.1.5-p273'
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/bin/rbenv exec"
set :rbenv_map_bins, %w{rake gem bundle ruby rails}

set :assets_roles, [:app]

# Default value for :scm is :git
set :scm, :git

# Default value for :linked_files is []
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/application.yml}

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5

# which config files should be copied by deploy:setup_config
# see documentation in lib/capistrano/tasks/setup_config.cap
# for details of operations
set(:config_files, %w(
  nginx.conf
  application.yml
  database.yml
  unicorn.rb
  unicorn_init.sh
))

# which config files should be made executable after copying
# by deploy:setup_config
set(:executable_config_files, %w(
  unicorn_init.sh
))

# files which need to be symlinked to other parts of the
# filesystem. For example nginx virtualhosts, log rotation
# init scripts etc. The full_app_name variable isn't
# available at this point so we use a custom template {{}}
# tag and then add it at run time.
set(:symlinks, [
  {
    source: "nginx.conf",
    link: "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/{{full_app_name}}"
  },
  {
    source: "unicorn_init.sh",
    link: "/etc/init.d/unicorn_{{full_app_name}}"
  },
  {
    source: "log_rotation",
    link: "/etc/logrotate.d/{{full_app_name}}"
  }
])

namespace :deploy do
  # compile assets locally then rsync
  after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'
end
```

All of the answers I found didn't have a solution or were for Capistrano 2, so I am wondering if the options have changed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I've made some progress, but it's still not reading my local repo. Here's the error message:

> SSHKit::Command::Failed: git exit status: 128 git stdout: Nothing
>   written git stderr: fatal: '/C:/Users/me/Documents/repo/myappname.git'
>   does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from
>   remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I've tried all different path combinations for my repo. My git repo is at the following path: `C:/Users/me/Documents/repo/myappname`. Is there a specific way to reference my local repo?

Comment: you are on windows??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not how Capistrano is designed to work. The basic assumption Capistrano makes is that your project resides in a repository that the server can access (almost always this is a Git repo hosted at e.g. Bitbucket or GitHub).

Capistrano *pulls* your source code by running git commands *on the server*. The server has no way to see your local repository, which is why it doesn't work.

There are some plugins that try to change Capistrano's behavior to allow for the *push* style deployment you are looking for. Search GitHub for "capistrano copy" and try them out. This one could be what you're looking for:

https://github.com/ydkn/capistrano-git-copy

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

I have been using capistrano-scm-copy to do my deploys via SCP upload from my dev box to AWS.  Note of caution - this is like running with scissors.  It's nice to be able to do a quick hotfix deploy, verily it in production and the do git commit.  But you need to be really careful to not forget the commit part.